# Two jar files into one exe

Tags: java

I've made **Tic Tac Toe** in Java and I've got two Jar files.

I want to put them both into one exe.

Is it even possible, or do I have to convert only `Main` file and another one another way?

I've never done this before.

Need suggestions for the implementation.

Comment: what for IDE did you use? Netbeans or Eclipse etc  because there are a few tutorials on how to do it out there in the Internet I think [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file) could help your

Comment: Why you want to build an exe file? Build an executable jar.

Comment: Why do you have two JAR files?

Comment: changed sentence structure

Answer (score 1):

To make an exe file you need to define one jar as a point of execution. That jar must contain a `main()` method.
If you have two jars and all contain main method, then you can call First's jar's main method in Second's main method and declare the Second jar as the point of execution.

Like this:

```
class First {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        //excution code
    }
}

class Second {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        First.main(arg);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help.